# Three Bags Marble Probability

Tags: probability, contest-math

I found this problem in a maths test, and although I am sure there is a method to solve it, I don't know how.

I have three bags. Two bags have identical contents- 1 black marble and 2 white ones. The third bag has 1 black marble and 3 white ones. I pick one bag at random and draw out a marble. What is the probability that this marble is black?

Please don't tell me he answer, just the method. I am new to probability, and I tried multiplying the probabilities, but I don't think I am on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ P(\text{Marble is black}) = \sum_i P(\text{Marble is black | came from bag i}) * P(\text{choosing bag i})$. You should easily be able to calculate $P(\text{Marble is black | came from bag i}) $.